# DNS server not taken into account anymore through my Samsung Galaxy S7 bluetooth tethring

Tags: networking, network-manager, bluetooth, dns

After trying to manually add routes in NetworkManager to my Bluetooth connection, il appears I cannot connect anymore even by deleting thoses additional routes.
I digged a bit to understand what happened and here is what I found :

when I connect through nm-applet all seems all right but internet is unreachable :

```
   # ping www.google.com
   ping: www.google.com: Nom ou service inconnu
```

The connection Information from NM shows the Primary DNS is correctly given by DHCP :

```
   Primary DNS:     192.168.44.1
```

Using this dns adress through interactive nslookup I can resolv www.google.com
So I manually added this DNS to resolvconf using : 
   echo nameserver 192.168.44.1|sudo resolvconf -a bnep0
where bnep0 is my bluetooth device name and Internet became reachable again.

So I tried to understand what append during the tethering process and added DEBUG log level to MB,DNS and BT domains of NetworkManager and obtained the following log :

```
Oct 28 22:43:27 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <info>  [1509223407.8541] device (94:7B:E7:8A:0F:65): Activation: (bluetooth) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Will connect via PAN.
Oct 28 22:43:27 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <debug> [1509223407.8586] dns-mgr: (device_ip6_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Oct 28 22:43:27 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <debug> [1509223407.8586] dns-mgr: (device_ip6_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Oct 28 22:43:27 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <debug> [1509223407.8587] dns-mgr: (device_ip6_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Oct 28 22:43:30 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <debug> [1509223410.8968] dns-mgr: (device_ip4_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Oct 28 22:43:30 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <debug> [1509223410.8969] dns-mgr: (device_ip4_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Oct 28 22:43:30 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <debug> [1509223410.8969] dns-mgr: (device_ip4_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
Oct 28 22:43:30 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <debug> [1509223410.9115] dns-mgr: (device_state_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Oct 28 22:43:30 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <debug> [1509223410.9116] dns-mgr: (update_routing_and_dns): queueing DNS updates (2)
Oct 28 22:43:30 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <debug> [1509223410.9119] dns-mgr: (update_routing_and_dns): DNS configuration changed
Oct 28 22:43:30 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <debug> [1509223410.9120] dns-mgr: (update_routing_and_dns): no DNS changes to commit (1)
Oct 28 22:43:30 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <debug> [1509223410.9120] dns-mgr: (device_state_changed): DNS configuration changed
Oct 28 22:43:30 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <debug> [1509223410.9120] dns-mgr: (device_state_changed): committing DNS changes (0)
Oct 28 22:43:30 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <debug> [1509223410.9120] dns-mgr: update-dns: updating resolv.conf
    Oct 28 22:43:30 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <debug> [1509223410.9121] dns-mgr: update-dns: updating plugin systemd-resolved
    Oct 28 22:43:30 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: ((devices/nm-device.c:9799)): assertion '<dropped>' failed
    Oct 28 22:43:30 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: ((devices/nm-device.c:9799)): assertion '<dropped>' failed
    Oct 28 22:43:30 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <debug> [1509223410.9600] dns-mgr: (device_ip4_config_changed): queueing DNS updates (1)
Oct 28 22:43:30 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <debug> [1509223410.9601] dns-mgr: (device_ip4_config_changed): DNS configuration did not change
Oct 28 22:43:30 hbrazzi-ThinkPad-T450s NetworkManager[24463]: <debug> [1509223410.9601] dns-mgr: (device_ip4_config_changed): no DNS changes to commit (0)
```

As you can see. There seems to be a problem in nm-device.c at line 9799 followed by the indication that DNS configuration is not changed. 
Now i am a bit stucked and help would be welcome.

As requested by jeremy31 here are my dns related packages :

```
# dpkg -l|grep dns
rc  dnsmasq-base                                    2.76-5ubuntu0.1                               amd64        Small caching DNS proxy and DHCP/TFTP server
ii  dnsutils                                        1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu5.2                amd64        Clients provided with BIND
ii  libdns-export162                                1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu5.2                amd64        Exported DNS Shared Library
ii  libdns162:amd64                                 1:9.10.3.dfsg.P4-10.1ubuntu5.2                amd64        DNS Shared Library used by BIND
ii  libnet-dns-perl                                 1.07-1                                        all          Perform DNS queries from a Perl script
ii  libnss-mdns:amd64                               0.10-8ubuntu1                                 amd64        NSS module for Multicast DNS name resolution
```

regards

Comment: Please edit the question to include results for `dpkg -l | grep dns`

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out, it's a bug in (at least) network-manager 1.4.4-1ubuntu3.2

I'm not sure when it was introduced or resolved, but with network-manager 1.8.2-1ubuntu1 dns resolution works properly on wwan/3g as well.

For ubuntu 17.04 i used the 1.8.2 version from artful-proposed: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/1.8.2-1ubuntu1/+build/13090166

You will need to update both libnm0 and network-manager: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/1.8.2-1ubuntu1/+build/13090166/+files/libnm0_1.8.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/1.8.2-1ubuntu1/+build/13090166/+files/network-manager_1.8.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

Download them, then install by:

```
sudo dpkg -i libnm0_1.8.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb network-manager_1.8.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

I restarted network-manager and modem-manager although I guess modem-manager was unnecessary.

```
sudo service network-manager restart
sudo service modem-manager restart
```